# SDL 2.0 - Rendering: PNG file doesn't render

Tags: c++, graphics, png, sdl, sdl-2

I am currently working on developing an in-house GUI for my own personal video game project, and I am currently done with creating the basic framework. It consists of these classes:

- GUI_Engine
- GUI_Element
- GUI_Panel
- GUI_Window

GUI_Element is an abstract base class for all my GUI classes I will create using my framework, and its child is GUI_Panel. GUI_Panel's child is GUI_Window.

GUI_Engine stores pointers to GUI_Element's and loads various PNG files to be used by all the GUI_Element's. These PNG files are stored in a SpritePool, a simple double vector that stores both SDL_Texture's as well as std::string's. The strings are the PNG file names.

I currently have two PNG files that are not rendering properly with the following code from the **void GUI_Window::render()** function, "window_top" and "window_bottom". These 16x16 files are tiles to render the top and bottom borders of the window; yet, they are the only two textures that are not rendering properly.

Here's the code for GUI_Element:

```
/*
Class:      GUI_Element
Purpose:    -To provide an ABSTRACT base class for all the GUI elements within the framework.

Notes:      >The class already holds basic functions for hot, cold, select, and deslect.
             Function pointers are going to use to provide callback/like functionality.

*/

#ifndef GUI_ELEMENT_H
#define GUI_ELEMENT_H

#include "globalvar.h"
#include "Input.h"
#include "SpritePool.h"

class GUI_Element
{
public:
    GUI_Element() {}
    GUI_Element(SpritePool gui_skin, int x, int y, int w, int h, bool visible,     GUI_Element* parent);
    virtual ~GUI_Element();

    //set functions
    void set_texture_ptr(SDL_Texture** texture) {texture_ptr = texture;}
    void set_parent_element(GUI_Element* parent);
    void set_frame(int x, int y, int w, int h);
    void set_offset_x(int i) {offset_x = i;}
    void set_offset_y(int i) {offset_y = i;}
    void set_x(int i) {frame.x = i;}
    void set_y(int i) {frame.y = i;}
    void set_w(int i) {frame.w = i;}
    void set_h(int i) {frame.h = i;}
    void set_visible(bool b);
    void set_hot(bool b);
    void set_selected(bool b);

    //get functions
    SDL_Texture** get_texture_ptr() {return texture_ptr;}
    GUI_Element* get_parent_element() {return parent_element;}
    SDL_Rect* get_frame() {return &frame;}
    int get_offset_x() {return offset_x;}
    int get_offset_y() {return offset_y;}
    int get_x() {return frame.x;}
    int get_y() {return frame.y;}
    int get_w() {return frame.w;}
    int get_h() {return frame.h;}

    //is_property functions
    bool is_visible() {return visible;}
    bool is_hot() {return hot;}
    bool is_selected() {return selected;}

    //on_action functions
    virtual void on_hot() = 0;
    virtual void on_cold() = 0;
    virtual void on_select() = 0;
    virtual void on_deselect() = 0;

    //render/update/check input functions
    virtual void render() = 0;
    virtual void update() = 0;
    virtual void check(Input &input) = 0;

protected:
    int offset_x, offset_y;

    SDL_Texture** texture_ptr;

    GUI_Element* parent_element;

    SDL_Rect frame;

    bool visible;
    bool hot;
    bool selected;

    void (*func_hot) ();
    void (*func_select) ();
    void (*func_cold) ();
    void (*func_deselect) ();


private:
};
```

and here's the code for GUI_Window:

```
#ifndef GUI_WINDOW_H
#define GUI_WINDOW_H

#include "GUI_Panel.h"

class GUI_Window : public GUI_Panel
{
public:
    GUI_Window(SpritePool gui_skin, int x, int y, int w, int h, bool visible, std::string str);
    virtual ~GUI_Window();

    void set_name(std::string str) {name = str;}
    void set_menubar_properties(bool minimize, bool pin, bool exit);
    void set_border_visible(bool b);
    void set_bg_visible(bool b);

    std::string get_name() {return name;}
    bool get_minimize_visible() {return minimize_visible;}
    bool get_pin_visible() {return pin_visible;}
    bool get_exit_visible() {return exit_visible;}
    bool get_border_visible() {return border_visible;}
    bool get_bg_visible() {return bg_visible;}

    virtual void on_hot();
    virtual void on_cold();
    virtual void on_select();
    virtual void on_deselect();

    //render/update/check input functions
    virtual void render();
    virtual void update();
    virtual void check(Input &input);

protected:
    std::string name;

    bool minimize_visible;
    bool pin_visible;
    bool exit_visible;
    bool border_visible;
    bool bg_visible;

    SDL_Rect tile_frame;

    SDL_Texture** window_top;
    SDL_Texture** window_bottom;
    SDL_Texture** window_left;
    SDL_Texture** window_right;
    SDL_Texture** window_topleft;
    SDL_Texture** window_topright;
    SDL_Texture** window_bottomleft;
    SDL_Texture** window_bottomright;
    SDL_Texture** window_minimize;
    SDL_Texture** window_pin;
    SDL_Texture** window_exit;
    SDL_Texture** gui_bg;

private:
};

#endif // GUI_WINDOW_H
```

and here's the code for GUI_Window::render():

```
void GUI_Window::render()
{
if (visible)
{
    if (bg_visible)
    {
        SDL_RenderCopy(g_renderer, *gui_bg, NULL, &frame);
    }

    if (border_visible)
    {
        tile_frame.x = frame.x;
        tile_frame.y = frame.y;
        tile_frame.w = 16;
        tile_frame.h = 16;

        SDL_RenderCopy(g_renderer, *window_topleft, NULL, &tile_frame);
        tile_frame.y = frame.y;

        while (tile_frame.x < (frame.x + frame.w - 32))
        {
            SDL_RenderCopy(g_renderer, *window_top, NULL, &tile_frame);
            tile_frame.x += 16;
        }

        tile_frame.x += 16;
        SDL_RenderCopy(g_renderer, *window_topright, NULL, &tile_frame);

        if (window_top == NULL)
            std::cout << "oh well" << std::endl;

        while (tile_frame.y < (frame.y + frame.h - 16))
        {
            tile_frame.y += 16;
            SDL_RenderCopy(g_renderer, *window_right, NULL, &tile_frame);
        }

        SDL_RenderCopy(g_renderer, *window_bottomright, NULL, &tile_frame);

        while (tile_frame.x > frame.x + 16)
        {
            tile_frame.x -= 16;
            SDL_RenderCopy(g_renderer, *window_bottom, NULL, &tile_frame);
        }

        tile_frame.x -= 16;
        SDL_RenderCopy(g_renderer, *window_bottomleft, NULL, &tile_frame);

        while (tile_frame.y > frame.y + 16)
        {
            tile_frame.y -= 16;
            SDL_RenderCopy(g_renderer, *window_left, NULL, &tile_frame);
        }
    }

    if (exit_visible)
    {
        tile_frame.x = frame.x + frame.w - 16;
        tile_frame.y = frame.y;
        SDL_RenderCopy(g_renderer, *window_exit, NULL, &tile_frame);
    }

    if (pin_visible)
    {
        tile_frame.x = frame.x + frame.w - 32;
        tile_frame.y = frame.y;
        SDL_RenderCopy(g_renderer, *window_pin, NULL, &tile_frame);
    }

    if (minimize_visible)
    {
        tile_frame.x = frame.x + frame.w - 48;
        tile_frame.y = frame.y;
        SDL_RenderCopy(g_renderer, *window_minimize, NULL, &tile_frame);
    }
}
}
```

I've checked the following:

1. GUI_Engine loads all PNG files correctly. No SDL_Texture* are NULL;
2. GUI_Window supposedly loads all the SDL_Texture* into SDL_Texture** correctly. None of these pointers are NULL.
3. The loop logic in GUI_Window::render() runs correctly.
4. Strangely, the top and bottom bars will render if the SDL_Texture** are changed to something other than window_top and window_bottom.

Note:

The SDL_Texture** names are the exact same as the PNG files.

Here's what it looks like:

[image: The top and bottom border texture, window_top and window_bottom, are the only ones that are not rendering. Could it be due to a PNG naming conflict?]

Edit: Here's the texture loading code in my SpritePool class:

```
void SpritePool::load_texture(std::string path)
{
SDL_Texture* loaded_texture = NULL;

SDL_Surface* loaded_surface = NULL;
loaded_surface = IMG_Load(path.c_str());
if (loaded_surface == NULL)
    std::cout << path << " unable to be loaded!" << std::endl;
else
{
    loaded_texture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(g_renderer, loaded_surface);
    if (loaded_texture == NULL)
        std::cout << path << " unable to be converted to SDL_Texture*!" << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << path << " loaded!" << std::endl;
}

SDL_FreeSurface(loaded_surface);

texture_pool.push_back(loaded_texture);
texture_names.push_back(path);
}
```

Someone please help me!

Comment: At first glance the logic seems sound so what I would suggest is putting some debug output in the rendering sub-loops ie printing out the x,y,w,h for the top and bottom border rendering loops.

Comment: It sounds like there's something wrong with the two textures/PNGs.  1. Try to render the textures once somewhere else (like at the position of window_top_left. 2. Check that the PNGs are correct. Is there something weird with the alpha? 3. Try copying another PNG that you know works into the PNG of window_top and window_bottom.

Comment: Yeah, actually, I did all three of these already. It seems that the problem lies with the **pointers**, as the files render okay if I load them as SDL_Texture* rather than SDL_Texture**. Weird. But why?

Comment: Post your loading code.

Comment: Okay, so I just added the texture loading code. It definitely works, though.

Comment: (In case you noticed, NM my previous comment!) Does it work when you change the `top` and `bottom` code to draw simple filled rectangles? This to rule out Texture errors and verify your placement code. You may have 'over optimized' the clockwise drawing. -- Only slightly related: you need to move `tile_frame.x += 16;` in the `top` drawing code before the `RenderCopy` line. Can `border_visible` be false *but* the top right icons visible anyway? In that case `tile_frame.w` and `.h` are not set.

Comment: Why are you using SDL_Texture** at all? Why do you need a pointer to a pointer? Why not simply pass around a simple pointer? This is pure speculation now because I can't see the code where you call `set_texture_pointer`: if you are getting the SDL_Texture** by doing something like `ptr = &texture_pool[i]` and then you keep adding other textures to `texture_pool` (which I assume is a vector), it's possible than when the `texture_pool` resizes internally, that the pointers are moved around and your SDL_Texture** are no longer valid.

Comment: Would need to see the code which calls `SpritePool::load_texture` and where you set `GUI_Window::window_top`.

Comment: Seems like it's off somewhere. Can you just clean up your code, put only the necessary bits and put the whole thing on a paste website?

Comment: @ysalmi You see, I treat the SDL_Texture* as if they were the actual objects because that's how they're naturally returned by the function that turns a SDL_Surface into a SDL_Texture. If this is wrong, it's clearly my bad; I've been programming on the side casually for less than about maybe 6 months more frequently, and I do not understand the internal workings of SDL.

Comment: To everyone else: I already fixed the problem, but it's quite weird: only the first two textures do not render unless I load them as SDL_Texture*.

Comment: @Cinch: `SDL_Texture` is the object and SDL is returning to you a pointer to the object. There is no need to store a pointer to this pointer. SDL stores the objects internally and gives you pointers to them. Perhaps check out a tutorial on c pointers: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_pointers.htm . They can occasionally be tricky.

Comment: Ah, thank you! I wasn't aware that SDL did this for you already! Silly me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking over my code, the problem was solved by turning SDL_Texture** into SDL_Texture*.

**Edit:** After about a year of programming, I can now say that the error with this problem lay in my use of SDL_Texture** with std::vector. While my vector held only regular pointers, I was handing out double pointers. However, when std::vector resizes itself, it will copy its internals to another space in memory, invalidating the double pointers.

- 1. The additional level of indirection was unrequired--SDL returns a pointer to the resource anyways, so I needed only to pass around the regular pointer value, which fixed the problem.
- 2. A second, but less robust solution would have been to reserve space for the std::vector before inserts, but this would inevitably again invalidate the double pointers once the vector copies itself.